# SWT List display line numbers

Tags: java, list, swt

How do I display line numbers on SWT list? I did refer to some posts on showing line numbers for StyledText but it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could use a `Table` with 2 columns without headers:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    table.setLinesVisible(false);
    new TableColumn(table, SWT.RIGHT);
    new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);

    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(0, row + "");
        item.setText(1, "Item " + row);
    }

    for(int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
    {
        table.getColumn(col).pack();
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever workaround indeed. I can use this for now, I guess. However, it would have really helped if SWT Lists had a method to show the line numbers.
Thanks Baz!

Comment: @user2033666 You're welcome. If you find a solution, come back and post it. If not, come back and consider accepting my answer :)